# Backgroundworker won't report progress

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, progress

I have a background worker running a long database task.  i want to show the progress bar while the task is running.  Somehow the background worker won't report the progress of the task.

This is what i have:

```
BackgroundWorker _bgwLoadClients;

_bgwLoadClients = new BackgroundWorker();
_bgwLoadClients.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
_bgwLoadClients.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_bgwLoadClients_DoWork);
_bgwLoadClients.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(_bgwLoadClients_RunWorkerCompleted);
_bgwLoadClients.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(_bgwLoadClients_ProgressChanged);
_bgwLoadClients.RunWorkerAsync(parms);

private void _bgwLoadClients_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = getdate();
    e.Result = dt;
}

void _bgwLoadClients_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

I am doing this in WPF, but i guess it won't make a difference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you indent your code by four spaces when you're typing (or editing) your question, it'll be displayed with indentation and formatting like code, rather than mashed together into a paragraph and hard to read.

Comment: You don't seem to be calling the .ReportProgress method of the BackgroundWorker - is that simply because you're showing us some simplified code?

Comment: @Mike, I think that's probably the reason rather than over editing of an example.

Comment: i cannot call the ReportProgress method because i am only doing one thing and one thing only inside the Dowork method.  i can put a .ReportProgress before and after the getdate() call, but the progress bar never progress while getdata() is called..

Comment: If what you are doing is not broken into steps, is it deterministic how long it will take?  If not, you will be unable to report anything except 0% or 100%.  You may want to use an indeterminate progress bar.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to break your DoWork method down into reportable progress and then call ReportProgress.

Take for example the following:

```
private void Something_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{
    // If possible, establish how much there is to do
    int totalSteps = EstablishWorkload();

    for ( int i=0; i<totalSteps; i++)
    {
        // Do something...

        // Report progress, hint: sender is your worker
        (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress((int)(100/totalSteps)*i, null);
    }

}
```

If your work can't be predetermined, try adding your own percentages:

```
private void Something_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{
    // some work

    (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(25, null);

    // some work

    (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(50, null);

    // some work

    (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(60, null);

    // some work

    (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(99, null);
}
```

Comment: Nice programming, bad math ;-) (int)(100.0 / totalSteps * i)

Answer (score 11):

Modify the **WorkReportProgress** property of the backgroundworker object to **true** either in the properties window or in code.

Comment: It would have literally saved me 20 minutes if they had defaulted that to true from the begining! Or let it become true when someone calls ReportProgress. Or thrown a better exception.
Thanks mate!

Answer (score 3):

You have to manualy call [`ReportProgress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx) to raise the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call worker.ReportProgress(percentComplete) in your DoWork method.
percentComplete should be computed based on the total work. For example:

```
for(int i =0; i != 100; i++) {
    // do something
    worker.ReportProgress(i);
}
```

Sometimes it is difficult to partition a job in several chunks to be possible to report the progress. Unfortunately the BackgroundWorker does not solve this, you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

just report progress on dowork event

```
private void _bgwLoadClients_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    int progresValue0to100 = 75;
    (sender as System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(progresValue0to100);
    //do your jobs..
}
```

it works like this

Answer (score 2):

Progress must be sent from within the DoWork event by calling the ReportProgress method on the BackgroundWorker. In your case, you can't report any progress because all of the work is being done outside of the DoWork function. You can only report progress before and after the call to getdate(), but not during the call since the BackgroundWorker thread is busy.