# Making a progress bar update in real time in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm having some trouble making the progress bar show the updates in real time.

This is my code right now

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
     progressbar1.Value = i;
     Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

But for some reason the progress bar shows empty when the function runs, and then nothing until the function finishes running. Can someone explain to me how this can be done? I'm new to C#/WPF so I'm not 100% sure on how I would implement a Dispatcher on a different thread (as seen on some other posts) to fix this problem.

To clarify, my program has a button which when press, grabs the value from a textbox, and uses an API to retrieve info, and create labels based on it. I want the progress bar to update after every row of data is finished processing.

This is what I have right now:

```
private async void search(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var progress = new Progress<int>(value => progressbar1.Value = value);
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
             some pre-processing before the actual for loop occur
             for (int i = 0; i < numberofRows; i++)
             {
                  label creation + adding
                  ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(i);
             }
        }));
    });
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22085142/906773 would be basically what you need. If you have trouble implementing it, could you show more of your actual code?

Comment: Get rid of the Dispatcher.Invoke - all you're doing is blocking the UI thread for the whole operation. Progress should handle synchronisation.

Comment: The problem is that without the Dispatcher.Invoke when the function tries to execute, this is what comes up. "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." This happens when the function tries to access what's inside a textbox.

Comment: On what line? Are you doing other UI work in there?  Add Dispatcher.Invoke only on the parts that are UI related.

Comment: Yes I'm creating labels, and adding it to the main grid. This also use some external API tools to get information, which goes into the label content.

Comment: I'd try not to do this. Have the Task process & return some results without touching the UI (other than progress), then update the UI when finished. Better still, look at MVVM for better separating your logic from your UI.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Managed to make it work. All I needed to do is instead of making it just

```
progressBar1.value = i;
```

I just had to do

```
progressbar1.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progressbar1.Value = i, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Comment: On the contrary, you need to *remove* the call to ` this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>`. By using `Task.Run` you are in a *background* thread and ask to execute the worker function in the *UI* thread. No wonder the progressbar can't update. In this answer you moved the progressbar update to a background thread, thus compounding the error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Mind sharing your solution?

Comment: @IamDOM in fact, this answer is doubly wrong - not only does it use an obsolete technique, it does so *in place of a good solution*. The question already uses `Progress< T>` so the code already runs in .NET 4.5,

Comment: If I saw somebody doing this in WPF, we'd have a serious talk about his career prospects.

Answer (score 31):

If you are using .NET 4.5 or later, you can use [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx):

```
var progress = new Progress<int>(value => progressBar.Value = value);
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(i);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
});
```

You need to mark your method with `async` keyword to be able to use `await`, for example:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: The problem is that my button click does a loop X times, and I want it so that after each loop, the progress bar updates :\ Can you help me implement this?

Comment: @nonion I don't quite understand what you need, but the principle is simple: put all you time-consuming work inside `await Task.Run(() => { }` block (you may have multiple such blocks in a method). And put `((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(i);` whenever you want to update the progress bar. You can put any integer value instead of `i` in the `Report` parameter, and it will be the new value of the progress bar.

Comment: Oh ok thank you a lot for the help. I tried to compile the code with that implemented and I get this error: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. This is when I try to change the label inside the grid.

Comment: Worked out how to fix it. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it) to make the program compiling, but now the problem I'm getting is that the same thing happens, which is that the bar doesn't automatically update

Comment: @nonion it's hard to say what is wrong without the actual code. Please update your post with your new code.

Comment: @nonion you didn't *fix* it, you covered up the bug inside `Task.Run`. Aleksey's answer works.

Comment: If I saw somebody doing this in WPF, we'd have a serious talk about his career prospects.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) included in .NET, which provides you with methods for reporting the progress of a background thread in an event. The thread which created the BackGroundWorker automatically calls this event.

The [BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) can be used to report the progress of an asynchronous operation to the user.

```
// This event handler updates the progress bar. 
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,
    ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Refer to MSDN for more information about using this.

Comment: If I saw somebody doing this in WPF, we'd have a serious talk about his career prospects.