# Parallel calls of two methods using threads - One executing before one finished

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, parallel-processing, backgroundworker

I am using multi threading in a C# application to upload images.

The flow is, first I am resizing the images.
                second I am uploading them.

Code is like :

Upload button click

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            ResizeImagesAtLocal();
            UploadImageToCloud();
}               


private void ResizeImagesAtLocal()
{
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker
                {
                    WorkerReportsProgress = true
                };

            worker.DoWork += worker_ResizeImages;
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ResizeProgressChanged;

            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void worker_ResizeProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ResizeProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void worker_ResizeImages(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}


private void UploadImageToCloud()
{
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.DoWork += worker_UploadImages;
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_UploadProgressChanged;

            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void worker_UploadProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UploadProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

void worker_UploadImages(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```

The problem is, ResizeImagesAtLocal is not yet finished, and the upload image started executing, which is causing issue..

Is there a way to make sure.. ResizeImagesAtLocal does all its job done, and then we can call the upload method.

Comment: Hint, use C#5 `async` `await`. Second hint. Why does the second task have to live on a second worker? Just bung them both in the same worker, and you KNOW that they will run sequentially.

Comment: I have designed the process like..all images will be resized and stored in a local folder. and then will upload them..ANd both will be showing there progress..so they need to be in different threads..

Comment: You are parallelizing all resizing with all uploading where as you should parallelize individual (synchronous resize & upload pairs)

Comment: From a C#4 perspective I completely agree with @cellik. However from C#5 onwards I would suggest using TPL Dataflow or Rx.Net. This is silly easy in either tech, and with BackgroundWorker its just silly.

Comment: How can I not block the UI thread to show progess of resizing in a synchronous way, with out using this approach..

Comment: @Akon everything within your `BW.DoWork` will be run on a worker thread. Use http://stackoverflow.com/a/854648/1808494 to update your UI between steps (hopefully with some kind of Controller). But for GAWDS SAKE YOU SHOULD NOT USE BACKGROUNDWORKER IF YOU CAN AVOID IT, USE TPL.

Comment: @Aron - Thanks..yes I should try with TPL...I used Backgrdworker..as I was bit comfortable with that and thought it will be quick...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) present from 4.0 version.

You can do (pseudocode):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> {
}). ContinuewWith(...);
```

`ContinueWith` will be called *after* `StartNew` task finished

Comment: @Akon, you can do that in C#5 as 5 > 4. Although I suggest using `Task.Run` instead, if you have C#5.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach to use if you're happy using Microsoft's Reactive Framework:

```
Func<Image, Image> resizeImage = i => { /* resize image */ };
Func<Image, System.Uri, bool> uploadImage = (i, u) => { /* upload image */ };
var uri = /* upload uri */;

var query =
    from image in images.Select((x, n) => new { x, n }).ToObservable()
    from thumbnail in Observable.Start(() => resizeImage(image.x))
    from uploaded in Observable.Start(() => uploadImage(thumbnail, uri))
    select new
    {
        image = image.x,
        index = image.n,
        thumbnail,
        uploaded,
    };

query
    .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        UploadProgress.Value = x.index * 100 / images.Count();
        /* do other stuff if needed on UI thread */
    });
```

That's it. It's all handled on background threads in parallel. It marshals the updates onto the UI thread. The `Subscribe` method returns an `IDispose` that can be used to stop the background threads. And it can all be coded in your `Click` event handler.